# cp949 codec can't encode character error in python

Tags: python

I am using the code below to parse the XML format wikipedia training data into a pure text file:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import logging
import os.path
import six
import sys

from gensim.corpora import WikiCorpus

if __name__ == '__main__':
    program = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
    logger = logging.getLogger(program)

    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    logging.root.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)
    logger.info("running %s" % ' '.join(sys.argv))

    # check and process input arguments
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Using: python process_wiki.py enwiki.xxx.xml.bz2 wiki.en.text")
        sys.exit(1)
    inp, outp = sys.argv[1:3]
    space = " "
    i = 0

    output = open(outp, 'w')
    wiki = WikiCorpus(inp, lemmatize=False, dictionary={})
    for text in wiki.get_texts():
        if six.PY3:
            output.write(bytes(' '.join(text), 'utf-8').decode('utf-8') + '\n')
        #   ###another method###
        #    output.write(
        #            space.join(map(lambda x:x.decode("utf-8"), text)) + '\n')
        else:
            output.write(space.join(text) + "\n")
        i = i + 1
        if (i % 10000 == 0):
            logger.info("Saved " + str(i) + " articles")

    output.close()
    logger.info("Finished Saved " + str(i) + " articles")
```

when I run this code, it gives me a following error message:

```
File "wiki_parser.py", line 42, in <module>
    output.write(bytes(' '.join(text), 'utf-8').decode('utf-8') + '\n')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp949' codec can't encode character '\u1f00' in position 1537: illegal multibyte sequence
```

When I searched this error online, most answers told me to add 'utf-8' as the encoding which is already there. What could be the possible issue with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Minimal example

The problem is that your file is opened with an implicit encoding (inferred from your system). I can recreate your issue as follows:

```
a = '\u1f00'
with open('f.txt', 'w', encoding='cp949') as f:
    f.write(a)
```

Error message: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp949' codec can't encode character '\u1f00' in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence`

You have two options. Either open the file using an encoding which can encode the character you are using:

```
with open('f.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(a)
```

Or open the file as binary and write encoded bytes:

```
with open('f.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(a.encode('utf-8'))
```

## Applied to your code:

I would replace this part:

```
output = open(outp, 'w')
wiki = WikiCorpus(inp, lemmatize=False, dictionary={})
for text in wiki.get_texts():
    if six.PY3:
        output.write(bytes(' '.join(text), 'utf-8').decode('utf-8') + '\n')
    #   ###another method###
    #    output.write(
    #            space.join(map(lambda x:x.decode("utf-8"), text)) + '\n')
    else:
        output.write(space.join(text) + "\n")
```

with this:

```
from io import open

wiki = WikiCorpus(inp, lemmatize=False, dictionary={})
with open(outp, 'w', encoding='utf=8') as output:
    for text in wiki.get_texts():
        output.write(u' '.join(text) + u'\n')
```

which should work in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think it's working but I have to wait because the file is pretty big. I will come back with the result!

Comment: It's not printing any of the "logger.info("Saved " + str(i) + " articles")" lines. Does it mean there is a problem?

Comment: @Dawn17 you probably forgot to indent those lines one level further.

Comment: so should it go inside `for text in wiki.get_texts():` this for-loop?

Comment: Yes, but I would actually advise you to rather use [tqdm](https://github.com/noamraph/tqdm) to show your progress in a nicer way.

Comment: @Dawn17 Consider accepting the answer if it has helped you.