# How to fix the error "Command errored out with exit status 1" when installing cdqa with pip?

Tags: python, character-encoding, pip

I am trying to install `cdqa` in my pc (Windows 10, python 3.7) using the command:

`> pip install cdqa`

but I'm getting an error. 
Here is the full log:

```
Collecting cdqa
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/02/ff021d2a34da02090b1e949e0edf354252668fb006e326def5c5e2b2bdcd/cdqa-1.3.5.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hys\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hzqdnquc\\cdqa\\setup
.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hys\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hzqdnquc\\cdqa\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().repl
ace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\hys\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hzqdnquc\cdqa\pip-
egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\hys\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hzqdnquc\cdqa\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\hys\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hzqdnquc\cdqa\setup.py", line 14, in <module>
        long_description=read("README.md"),
      File "C:\Users\hys\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hzqdnquc\cdqa\setup.py", line 6, in read
        return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), file)).read()
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 2685: illegal multibyte sequence
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I don't know what should I do.

Comment: The file is being read using 'cp949' decoder when it should probably be something else because the byte sequence: 0xf0 can't be decoded. maybe 'utf-8'? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545946/cp949-codec-cant-encode-character-error-in-python

Comment: It's interesting that it says "cp949". That's a Hangul Windows code page. Is your OS in Korean? BTW welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: To be clear, I think `open` is assuming the encoding based on your environment (OS)

Comment: Yes, my OS is Windows10 in Korean.

Comment: @kyysyb Try running the `pip install` command under a different locale. I don't know how to do that on Windows, but on Linux it's done with environment variables, e.g. `LC_ALL=C pip install ...`